# ¿como creo una aplicacion dinamica en React.js que pinte en pantalla todos los componentes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

soy nuevo en react.js y quiero crear una fabrica de objetos de react.js que pinte en pantalla  los componentes de cualquier json.

Lo que he realizado hasta ahora es una aplicación que lee un json y pinto los componentes yo mismo, lo que necesito es que estos componentes se pinten automaticamente.

```
class Seccion extends React.Component {
    state = {};
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            tabla
        }
    }

    handleChange = name => event =>{      
       console.log(event.target.value)
        this.setState({
            [name]: event.target.value,
        })      
      };

      handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log('El boton fue apretado');
        console.log(this.state);
      };

    render() {
        const muestra = this.state.tabla.map((tab, i) => {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td value="orden">{tab.orden}</td> 
                    <td value="etiqueta">{tab.etiqueta}</td>              
                    <td value="tipo">{tab.tipo}</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text"  value={this.state.valorCampo.id} onChange={this.handleChange(tab.etiqueta)} className="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="Badge_header2">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div className="card" >
                                <div className="card-header">
                                    <h3 className="text-center"> Seccion 1</h3>
                                    {muestra}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-success">Cotizar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
        );
    } }

export default Seccion;
```

esta es mi aplicación que lee el json y con base a el, hago los componentes que utilizara, pero quiero que estos campos se hagan de forma dinámica y si utilizo otro json puedan pintarse.

Comment: Hola José, bienvenido a SO.es. No me queda claro lo que has hecho y lo que quieres, si pudieras dar mas detalles de del resultado esperado y del actual, podrías recibir más ayuda de la comunidad. Aparte revisa tu código, ya que tiene errores de sintaxis. Todo lo que haces dentro de `return` no está permitido en JS. Entra a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta. Saludos

Comment: hola, muchas gracias, explicare mejor.

Comment: lo que deseo que haga mi aplicación es que pueda pintar en pantalla los componentes necesarios, para cualquier json. En otras palabras es que si cambio de json se puedan pintar los componentes que necesita el json que cargue